# Use jquery,ajax to display items with laravel framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am working on a page that displays products.So far i had a route like :

```
Route::get('products/{category}/{subcategory}')
```

and in my controller i send back results from database, to display items.
But i decide to display items with jquery and ajax calls and not with php. So when i navigate to this page i will use $.get() method to take items from server and display them.My problem is that i dont know how to take the parameters (category, subcategory) from the url so i can send them to server and take back the response.Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it like below in your blade view using the route method to get the route parameters or send the parameter to view using the controller

```
<script>
    $.get('products/{{request()->route("category")}}/{{request()->route("subcategory")}}')
</script>
```

in above code {{ }} statement will replace by the parameters respectively. you can check that in your source code. and if you want to access using javascript only then use `window.location.href` and split it using `.` and then access the part in which category and subcategory resides.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about dataTable with laravel. See documentation [here](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter). I think [dataTable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) is best option for you.